# Who was the sadhu from whom Tenali rama received the mantra?

Tags: rishi

Tenaliramans story is 5-6 century year old and he got blessings of maa-kaali. In dattatreya tantra, Shiva said that no mantras will work in kaliyuga except those which He mentioned in this work.

However, my question is about a sadhu who gave Tenali the mantra. Who was he? And I need some scriptural evidences of Tenaliraman which are somewhat rare ones.

Comment: I am yet to read Dattatreya Tantram, since u hv read it already, can u say what exactly the verse says about no mantras being effective in Kali Yuga.. if possible, can u give the verse?

Comment: @Rickross https://archive.org/details/DattatreyaTantraBabuShyamaSundarLalTripathi/page/n7

Comment: Page 6 of book 1st verse